# Loading view lag

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, lag

Apologies for unclear question. here the fixed answer:

In my initial view controller, I have two round buttons.it used to be an UIImage view + a gesture recogniser(for ux reasons), when I was prototyping, It worked well on iPhone 4 and higher.
Now I replace the UIImage + gesture with proper round UIbuttons that I create programmatically as follow inside a method that I call in viewDidLoad:

```
self.featureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[_featureButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FeaturedArtistImage.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_featureButton.layer.cornerRadius = size/2;
_featureButton.frame =CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-size/2, 50, size, size);
_featureButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
_featureButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
_featureButton.layer.borderWidth=5.0f;

[_featureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[self.view insertSubview:self.featureButton belowSubview:self.artistLabel];
```

As matt recommended to use the main thread to create those buttons I added this:

```
 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ { 
//Create buttons here
 }];
```

I definitely have better performance, but after calling the VC a few time the app FPS drops, the ui element disappear and reappear one by one after a few seconds (I have 3 UILabels and 4 UIButtons) and finally it crashes on iPhone 4S, which I think is surprising.

I am thinking it might come from another VC that is being called before going to the main one after launch.On this one I also create UIButtons, but using a Subclass.

```
    #import "RoundButtonClass.h"

@implementation RoundButtonClass
{   CGFloat centerViewX;
    CGFloat centerViewY;
    CGFloat startAngle;
    CGFloat endAngle;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {


        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.7];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(actionFinished) name:@"shared" object:nil];



    }
    return self;
}



-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // do work here
        UIImage *maskedImage = [self maskImage:self.mainBkg withMask:self.maskImage];
        [self setBackgroundImage:maskedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        if (self.isFree == YES ) {
            self.frame = self.freeFrame;
        }
        else{


            centerViewX = (self.frame.size.width/4)*2 - self.size/2.0;
            centerViewY = self.frame.size.height/4 - self.size/2.0 + self.offset;

        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.size/2.0f;
        self.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth=3.0f;
        self.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Cond" size:70];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(touch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


                             }];

                         }];
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably creating the buttons and adding them to the interface in a background thread. That's illegal and will cause the delay you're describing.

Comment: That was it, I am using   ' [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {}]' to create any UI element programmatically, there is no more lag.
Thank you matt.